# Log in activity development in android using php and mysql but nothing is happening

Tags: android, onclick

My `admin_login` Java class:

```
public class admin_login extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=15000;
    private EditText etEmail;
    private EditText etPassword;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_login_main_lay);

        // Get Reference to variables
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    }

    // Triggers when LOGIN Button clicked
    public void checkLogin(View arg0) {

        // Get text from email and passord field
        final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
        final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        Toast.makeText(admin_login.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // Initialize  AsyncLogin() class with email and password
        new AsyncLogin().execute(email,password);
    }

    private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(admin_login.this);
        HttpURLConnection conn;
        URL url = null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            //this method will be running on UI thread
            pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
            pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
            pdLoading.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                // Enter URL address where your php file resides
                url = new URL("http://www.uprtou.ac.in/and_login.php");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }
            try {
                // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
                try {
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                // Append parameters to URL
                Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("username", params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter("password", params[1]);
                String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                // Open connection for sending data
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(query);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                conn.connect();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            }

            try {

                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                // Check if successful connection made
                if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    // Read data sent from server
                    InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                    return(result.toString());

                } else {

                    return("unsuccessful");
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "exception";
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //this method will be running on UI thread

            pdLoading.dismiss();

            if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
                /* Here launching another activity when login successful. If you persist login state
                use sharedPreferences of Android. and logout button to clear sharedPreferences.
                 */

                Intent intent = new Intent(admin_login.this,admin_home.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                admin_login.this.finish();

            } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {

                // If username and password does not match display a error message
                Toast.makeText(admin_login.this, "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {

                Toast.makeText(admin_login.this, "OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!--  Email Label -->


    <TextView
        android:text="Username"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/tv1" />

    <EditText
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Password"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView3" />

    <EditText
        android:text=""
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/text_border"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:password="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Login"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

    <Button
        android:text="Signup"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="checkLogin()"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Now nothing is happening, only the layout is showing. But when I click on login button nothing is happening. I have tried many times...

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` tag in your layout [should not contain parentheses](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html). It should look like this: `android:onClick="checkLogin"`.

Comment: @ShahbazAhmad Strange, are you getting any errors in logcat?